# How to Save and Restore the Scroll Position and State of ListView

Tags: android, listview, file-upload, android-viewholder

Let's see **screenshots** of work, for better understanding of **issue**:

1. I have **uploaded** first list item's image to server [**i.e**:- `Thumbnail 1.png`], see below image:

[image]

2. I got uploaded Image under **myfile** folder, using **Localhost**:

[image]

3. When I **scrolls down** `ListView`, getting this - here comes the actual pain, as you can see `Thumbnail 7`, i have not clicked on it:

[image]

4. And when again i **scrolls up** `ListView`, getting something this - that's irritating me, in a same way for `Thumbnail 2`, i did not touch that:

[image]

I think `that's enough` to explain you, **what** i am trying to do, what's **happening** and **where** i am getting issue

**So now your turn to let me know the solution, How can i resolve this issue ?**

**Some Explanation:**

I have uploaded first list item's image to server (and as per my requirement i got status of image as "uploaded" and upload button is now disabled) but when i scroll down/up listview its showing any one of the item in a list as uploaded not that one i have uploaded (i noticed mainly that list item which is visible) and resetting status of first list item which originally uploaded to server...

So here i just want to make upload status stable for that particular one which i have uploaded originally... not any of the visible item (those have not uploaded yet)

Just effecting on listview, nothing happening to server (getting only one image which i have uploaded)

**MainActivity.java:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

    static ListView lstView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();;

    static List <String> ImageList;
    String strPath;     

    int position ;

    static File f;
    File newFile;


    static File[] files ;
    static File  file ;

    ViewHolder holder;
    View v ;        

    String fileName;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);      

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
    ImageList = getSD();

    // ListView and imageAdapter
    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    }

    private List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();
        File f = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/mydata/");
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();

        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)
        {
            File  file = files[i];
            Log.d("Count",file.getPath());
            it.add (file.getPath());
        }
        return it;
    }   

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }                

        TextView textName;
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView textStatus;
        Button btnUpload;            

    }  

     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
        {
            public ImageAdapter(Context c)
            {

            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return ImageList.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Avoid unneccessary calls to findViewById() on each row, which is expensive!

            holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_main, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            // Create a ViewHolder and store references to the children views
            holder.textName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textName);
            holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);                
            holder.btnUpload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            holder.textStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

            // The tag can be any Object, this just happens to be the ViewHolder
            convertView.setTag(holder);                
            } else {                    
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();             
            }

            strPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Get File Name
            fileName = strPath.substring( strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length() );
            file = new File(strPath);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            long length = file.length();
            holder.textName.setText(fileName);


            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath,options);
            holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bm);       

            //btnUpload
            holder.btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Upload                           
                    startUpload(position);
                }
            });

            return convertView;

        }   
    }



            // Upload

            public void startUpload(final int position) {      

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    holder.btnUpload.setEnabled(false);

                        new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    new Thread(runnable).start();
                    }

                    // Async Upload
                    public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

                        String resServer;

                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

                        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                        byte[] buffer;
                        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
                        int resCode = 0;
                        String resMessage = "";

                        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                        String twoHyphens = "--";
                        String boundary =  "*****";

                        // File Path
                        String strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

                        // Upload to PHP Script
                        String strUrlServer = "http://10.0.2.2/uploadFile.php";

                        try {
                            /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                            File file = new File(strSDPath);
                            if(!file.exists())
                            {   
                                resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Message\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                                return null;
                            }

                        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

                        URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            conn.setDoInput(true);
                            conn.setDoOutput(true);
                            conn.setUseCaches(false);
                            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                                .getOutputStream());
                            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                            outputStream
                            .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                                    + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        // Read file
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        while (bytesRead > 0) {
                            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                        }

                        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                        // Response Code and  Message
                        resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                            if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                            {
                                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        int read = 0;
                        while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                            bos.write(read);
                        }

                        byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                            bos.close();

                        resMessage = new String(result);

                        }

                        Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
                        Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

                        fileInputStream.close();
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();

                        resServer = resMessage.toString();


                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return null;
                        }

                        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
                            statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
                            }

                        }


                    // When Upload Finish
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    protected void statusWhenFinish(int position, String resServer) {


                    /*** Default Value ***/
                    String strStatusID = "0" ;
                    String strError = "" ;

                    try {      

                    JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
                    strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
                    strError = c.getString("Message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }                                                                  

                    // prepare Status
                    if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
                    {                         
                        // When update Failed
                       holder.textStatus.setText("Failed");
                       holder.btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        holder.textStatus.setText("Uploaded");  
                        holder.btnUpload.setEnabled(false);
                    }

            }

}
```

Comment: thers is common strStatusID holding for all views , i guess that is making issue when scrollling the listview, try to hold row info in 1 item of arraylist and the use notify adapter

Comment: @Diva hello can you ellaborate it and place changes as you want me to do ...

Comment: For this type of problem , You have to add one one data structure which contains name of image and other status of image upload. When you click on button you have to make status of that object i,e status of image upload to be true. in get view you have to put your logic that if image status of that object is true , you will show uoloaded as text other wise you will show button.

Comment: @sun in your code there is global variale of status right? there status sould hold for all ros in listview , hence make a arrylist stating all state of single row

Comment: @Diva show me your suggestion by editing my existing code.. so i would be able to make changes and to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a structure like below :

```
/**
 * Introduce a class with below attributes to hold a state of each row in single
 * element
 * 
 */
public class MyData {
    /* Image url or path of image in single row */
    private String images;

    /* anme of image in single row */
    private String name;

    /* status ID of image in single row */
    private String statusID;

    /* message of image in single row */
    private String message;

    // Generate getters and setter
    public String getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(String images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getStatusID() {
        return statusID;
    }

    public void setStatusID(String statusID) {
        this.statusID = statusID;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Added appropriate comments to understand the code.

// MyDataList is the arrylist ArrayList(), you need to init this data structure in constructor

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyData fields = MyDataList.get(position);
}
```

**Edit :**

I have edite the code above posted , Look at code below how i used The MyData to set the status

```
package com.example.trial;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static ListView lstView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();;
    static List<MyData> ImageList;
    String strPath;
    int position;
    File newFile;
    ViewHolder holder;
    View v;
    String fileName;
    ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        ImageList = getSD();
        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        lstView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    private List<MyData> getSD() {
        List<MyData> it = new ArrayList<MyData>();
        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File f = new File(root_sd + "/Download");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            Log.d("Count", file.getPath());
            MyData data = new MyData();
            data.setImages(file.getPath());
            data.setStatusEnable(true);
            it.add(data);
        }
        return it;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View convertView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        TextView textName;
        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView textStatus;
        Button btnUpload;

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ImageList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // Avoid unneccessary calls to findViewById() on each row, which is
            // expensive!

            holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.adapter_main, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

                // Create a ViewHolder and store references to the children
                // views
                holder.textName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textName);
                holder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                holder.btnUpload = (Button) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
                holder.textStatus = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

                // The tag can be any Object, this just happens to be the
                // ViewHolder
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.btnUpload.setEnabled(ImageList.get(position)
                    .isStatusEnable());
            holder.textStatus.setText(ImageList.get(position).getMessage());
            strPath = ImageList.get(position).getImages().toString();

            // Get File Name
            fileName = strPath.substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1,
                    strPath.length());
            File file = new File(strPath);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            long length = file.length();
            holder.textName.setText(fileName);

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath, options);
            holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // btnUpload
            holder.btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Upload
                    startUpload(position);
                }
            });

            return convertView;

        }
    }

    // Upload

    public void startUpload(final int position) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        v = lstView.getChildAt(position
                                - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                        synchronized (this) {
                            ImageList.get(position).setStatusEnable(false);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }

    // Async Upload
    public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String resServer;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int resCode = 0;
            String resMessage = "";

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";

            // File Path
            String strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).getImages().toString();

            // Upload to PHP Script
            String strUrlServer = "http://mymasterpeice.comxa.com/uploadFile.php";

            try {
                /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                File file = new File(strSDPath);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Message\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                    return null;
                }

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                        strSDPath));

                URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream
                        .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                                + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);

                // Response Code and Message
                resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                        bos.write(read);
                    }

                    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                    bos.close();

                    resMessage = new String(result);

                }

                Log.d("resCode=", Integer.toString(resCode));
                Log.d("resMessage=", resMessage.toString());

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                resServer = resMessage.toString();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            statusWhenFinish(position, resServer);
        }

    }

    // When Upload Finish
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    protected void statusWhenFinish(int position, String resServer) {

        /*** Default Value ***/
        String strStatusID = "0";
        String strError = "";

        try {

            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
            strError = c.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // // prepare Status
        if (strStatusID.equals("0")) {
            // When update Failed
            ImageList.get(position).setMessage("Failed");
            ImageList.get(position).setStatusEnable(true);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            ImageList.get(position).setMessage("Uploded");
            ImageList.get(position).setStatusEnable(false);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Introduce a class with below attributes to hold a state of each row in
     * single element
     * 
     */
    public class MyData {
        /* Image url or path of image in single row */
        private String images;

        /* anme of image in single row */
        private String name;

        /* status ID of image in single row */
        private String statusID;

        /* message of image in single row */
        private String message;

        private boolean statusEnable;

        public boolean isStatusEnable() {
            return statusEnable;
        }

        public void setStatusEnable(boolean statusEnable) {
            this.statusEnable = statusEnable;
        }

        // Generate getters and setter
        public String getImages() {
            return images;
        }

        public void setImages(String images) {
            this.images = images;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getStatusID() {
            return statusID;
        }

        public void setStatusID(String statusID) {
            this.statusID = statusID;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: but how can i use it in my existing code ? or diva can you check at your end... if you want so i can place xmls and php code as well

Comment: you need to create a arrylist of that data

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of datatype you want to use. E.g.

```
class YourDataType{
    String name, status;
    Bitmap image;
}
```

Then use a list to hold all the objects you have in your list.

```
List<YourDataType> listOfObjects;
```

Then create the adapter with parameters like and pass the list of objects to your adapter's constructor.

```
class ImagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public ImagesAdapter(Context c, List<YourDataType> listOfObjects){
        this.listOfObjects = listOfObjects;
    }

    public View getView(params, position){
        YourDataType data = listOfObjects.get(position);
        //Here you can use data to access specific object and upload the specific image and then mark this object's status to marked, then you can change the status of any listview item relevant to the object.
        if(data.status == uploaded)
             viewHolder.textStatus.setText("Uploaded");
    }
}
```

And the best practice is to separate the adapter
Hope it helps. If you have any further questions comment below.

Comment: i am trying your way but i have some confusions in my mind and facing some problem while implementing this, can you make changes in my existing code ? i would be more thankful because bro its little urgent

Answer (score 0):

You should have a Array of `Upload Status` which is to be passed to the Adapter with default value is false and each time you successfully upload a file on server change the status into the Array corresponding to that position of listitem.

For example

Default Array (Assume size of list is 7)

```
{"false","false""false""false""false""false""false"}
```

Each time you successfully upload a file, change the status of Array to

```
{"false","true""false""false""false""false""true"}
```

Now you only need to update the values in this array and have to call

```
youradapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```

Comment: show me your suggestion by editing my existing code.. so i would be able to make changes and to understand - i am already using ((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Sun You need to understand the problem and have to fix the solution on your own. This is what we developers do.